# Mistake in Asher Yatzer and Rafa'ainu of Shemoneh Esrei

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, asher-yatzar

What would be the halacha in the following 2 cases:

A person davening Shemoneh Esrei instead of ending off the bracha of Rafa'ainu "rofeh cholei amo yisrael" (in his nusach) they ended of "rofeh col baser u'mfli l'asos (the chasima of Asher Yatzer.) Were they yotzee b'dieved? Must they say this bracha over again? If they finished davening Shemoneh Esrei must they go back and daven again?

Or what about if in Asher Yatzer instead of ending of "rofeh col baser u'mafli l'asos" the person ended off "rofeh cholei amo yisrael". Are they yotzee? If it's after toch c'dei dibbur must the bracha be said over again?

I've heard and seen before that by Shemoneh Esrei the middle part of the bracha doesn't have to be "exact". However that the end of the bracha (chasima) has to be exact in the way that Chazal formed the bracha.

Seemingly the same should be true by Asher Yatzer that one couldn't change the nusach (or would at least be yotzee b'dieved) in the case that they ended off the bracha differently.

Comment: כל המשנה ממטבע שטבעו חכמים בברכות לא יצא ידי חובתו (*berachos* 40b).